# Image view doesn't appear on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to add background image onto my screen and set some constraints, but unfortunately the image view doesn't appear and I don't know what the reason is. I've checked if the image file is in the project folder.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       setBackground()
    }

    func setBackground() {
        view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        backgroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "background-test-image")
    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your image in the Assets.xcassets folder

[image]